# Where does Firefox determine the words typed in URL bar are to be converted to search

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to find the area in Firefox source where after the user hits enter, the words entered in the url bar are identified to be fed to default search engine. So like for instance if I typed `firefox` it will pull up search results. I can't find where this logic is happening.

I traced like this starting with what call the searchbar makes on enter, and then went deeper, tracking url and any other uri's that were passed along the way.

1. gURLBar.handleCommand
2. openUILinkIn
3. openLinkIn
4. gBrowser.loadURIWithFlags

So modding the function openLinkIn to do a console.log before `loadURIWithFlags` we see url is still the search terms up to this point.

5. gBrowser.mCurrentBrowser.loadURIWithFlags
6. _loadURIWithFlags
7. gBrowser.webNavigation.loadURIWithOptions -- > `[[native code]`

So i traced by injecting into these function and I find right before it calls native code, it is passing a uri that is still the search term, it is mind boggling, i thought by that point (before passing to native code) it would have figured out the default search engine submission url and then pass it that. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think that your analysis is correct - the browser actually navigates to the URL with search keywords. And then the content process sends the [Browser:URIFixup message](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/eaf4f9b45117/browser/base/content/tab-content.js#l583) which is [received in browser.js again](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/eaf4f9b45117/browser/base/content/browser.js#l1255) and triggers `gKeywordURIFixup` function. That's where the keywords are resolved then. Yes, things used to be a lot simpler before Mozilla started working on process separation.

Comment: Thanks very much! I am trying to write a simple addon to restore the "Im Feeling Lucky" but instead of google im using ddg so its now "Im Feeling Ducky" :) https://duck.co/forum/thread/4698/google-s-feeling-lucky ill look into this and update you on how it goes :)

Comment: Hey @Wladamir I tried setting `window.gKeywordURIFixup = function() { console.error('here') }` but its never triggering :(

Comment: Whats interesting is that `Services.obs.addObserver({observe:function(a,b,c){console.error('incoming uri fixup:', a, b, c)}}, "keyword-uri-fixup", false);` triggers in beta Fx38 but not in Nightly :(

Comment: So I was adding that observer to catch the fixup and then i was trying to change the uri: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/71bb1b73fd123a7ef45b right now its not redirecting. but the bigger issue is how come nightly is not firing this observer :(